# Decoding botched escaped unicode from SQL Server in Python?

Tags: python, sql-server, unicode

I have a CSV file, appears to be UTF-16, dumped from SQL Server. This file contains properly encoded accents (spanish) but some of the rows are encoded differently. Like this:

```
0xd83d0xde1b0xd83d0xde1b0xd83d0xde1b
```

This seems to be a strange encoding for

```
\ud83d\ude1b\ud83d\ude1b\ud83d\ude1b
```

`\ud83d\ude1b` are surrogate pairs for an emoji

I need to convert everything to a nice, neat UTF-8 file. I tried endless combinations of `bytearray()`, `encode()`, `decode()`, and so on.

How can I convert this file of mixed UTF-16 and escaped UTF-16 into proper Python 3 strings, and finally save them to a new UTF-8 file?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the hex data like this:

```
>>> import binascii
>>> s = '0xd83d0xde1b0xd83d0xde1b0xd83d0xde1b'


>>> # Remove the leading '0x'
>>> hs = s.replace('0x', '')

>>> # Convert from hex to bytes
>>> bs = binascii.unhexlify(hs)
>>> bs
b'\xd8=\xde\x1b\xd8=\xde\x1b\xd8=\xde\x1b'

# Decode to str
>>> bs.decode('utf-16be')
''
```